# List active statements on firebird 1.5

Tags: firebird, firebird1.5

How to get the current number of active transactions/statements in firebird 1.5?
I know after 2.1 there is a MON$STATEMENTS table which holds the current active transactions, but only after version 2.1, does anybody know if there is a way of knowing this?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no way to do that in versions before the introduction of the monitoring tables.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird 2.0 or earlier there is no way to obtain a list of active statements with a plain Firebird install.

My first suggestion would be to upgrade. The last Firebird 1.5 release was in 2009, since then a lot of new features were introduced and bugs were fixed. For example the monitoring tables add in Firebird 2.1, and the trace facility added in Firebird 2.5.

However if you are really stuck on Firebird 1.5, then you might be able to use [FBScanner from IBSurgeon](http://www.ib-aid.com/en/fbscanner-firebird-scanner/). FBScanner is a 'proxy' for Firebird that records all kinds of information. Your applications talk to FBScanner as if it is a Firebird server, FBScanner records info (like transaction start/end, statement prepare and execute, etc), and then FBScanner forwards the request to the real Firebird database. However even FBScanner is more powerful when used against a newer Firebird version.

Comment: Thanks, as i am stuck in 1.5, this is goind to be a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your application if your database component supports it.  But it will only show you the stats from that app.  This is normally all I am interested in.

I use Delphi 2007 and IBO